# Entity Framework not picking up relationships after primary key changed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 update3, Entity Framework 5.0 based data model is not picking up pk-fk relationship after I changed the primary key from SAM_ID to ID in PERSON table in SQL Server 2012.

All constraints were re-created without any issues. The diagrams in SQL Server are showing the correct relationships.

I have tried cleaning the solution in Visual Studio and recreating the ADO.NET Entity Data Model but relationships are still not there between the table holding the primary key and the tables holding foreign keys.

**Primary Key table PERSON**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PERSON](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(100001,1) NOT NULL,
    [SAM_ID] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MANAGER_SAMID] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [IMAGE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [MANAGER_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PERSON_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Foreign Key table INFO**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INFO](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PERSON_ID] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_INFO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[INFO]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_INFO_PERSON] FOREIGN KEY([PID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PERSON] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[INFO] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_INFO_PERSON]
GO
```

What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

This SO post provided a hint and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576610/entity-framework-db-first-not-picking-up-relation

Before changing the PK I had added a unique constraint on the would-be-PK. Apparently after making it the PK, the unique constraint needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with VS2013 Update 4: The Model diagram was not showing my table relationships. I originally had a unique index constraint on columns that were eventually changed to a PK. Removing the unique index constraint from the PK allowed the Model diagram to pick up the table relationships.